# How to make BT keyboard available at login and OS selection screens

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Is it possible to have my bluetooth keyboard active before I enter into the desktop environment?  I'm unable to type in my login and password at the login screen because the Debian hasn't associated with my bluetooth keyboard until I manually tell it too.

Also can I extend bluetooth keyboard useability to Grub's dualboot screen as well?

At this stage I have to plug in my wired keyboard just to deal with these two events.  Can you show me how to set up my wireless keyboard to be automatically available at the boot screen, or at least at the login screen.

I'm currently using the default Bluetooth manager with Unity, Ubuntu 11.04, and pairing is rather difficult and non-automated, and does not extend to outside of the desktop environment.  (In fact I have to remove it and re-pair it every time and it does not even work reliably.)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How does your Bluetooth connect to your computer? Is it through a USB dongle? If it is USB it could be more a BIOS problem than a Linux one. Look at your BIOS and see it you can enable USB (Legacy USB?)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/242457/use-bluetooth-keyboard-to-access-edit-bios/242469#242469 might be of help

Comment: @arochester: I've pasted all my BIOS details into the original post.  Yes, connection is through a USB dongle, Iogear Model [GBU421](http://www.iogear.com/product/GBU421/).  With this new information, can you tell me what you think?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% but I think usb dongles don't work by them selves. They are just transmit/receivers with the OS driver doing the actual work. So I wouldn't bother with BIOS settings.

I have the `bluez` package installed, it provides a daemon that runs before I login to my desktop. Without doing anything more than pairing the bt device the first time after logging in, the system *sees* it normally the next time it boots before the login.

It works for my mouse, I guess it should also work for keyboards.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I overlooked your post.  Are you saying you can use your BT keyboard in the GRUB boot menu?

Comment: @ptrcao: No, sorry, I'm saying that it probably can't happen (not 100% sure though). I misread your question and thought you needed the BT K/B to work at the login screen (before loading users settings). My bad.

Comment: I wanted to know both actually...